# Make font awesome icon change color when select menu changes.

Tags: javascript, select

Newbie here, I am working really hard on understanding JavaScript but I need a little push in the right direction.

I have a fundamental knowledge of HTML and CSS. 
Could you tell me which language I need to use to complete my goal, do I need Bootstrap, etc etc?

This is just an example of what I am working on.
I need the font awesome icon to change to the color of what option the user has chosen from the dropdown menu.

Here is the HTML for my example.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <table> 
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
            <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
            <option value="red">RED</option>
            <option value="green">GREEN</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <td>
            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
        </td>
        </tr>
</table>
<style>
<!--Help here! -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I have updated the answer to show how to add the event handler using `on()` (see comments).

You just need to add a handler to the `change` event of the `select` element.

You can do it with [`change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/):

```
$('#my_select').change( function() {
    $('#icon_phone').css( 'color', $(this).val() );
});
```

Or with [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('#my_select').on( 'change', function() {
    $('#icon_phone').css( 'color', $(this).val() );
});
```

When it changes, add a new CSS rule to the *font awesome* icon.

```js
$('#my_select').change( function() {
    $('#icon_phone').css( 'color', $(this).val() );
});

$('#my_select2').on( 'change', function() {
    $('#icon_phone').css( 'color', $(this).val() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <table> 
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="my_select" >
                <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
                <option value="red">RED</option>
                <option value="green">GREEN</option>
            </select>
            <select id="my_select2" >
                <option value="blue">BLUE</option>
                <option value="red">RED</option>
                <option value="green">GREEN</option>
            </select>        </td>
    <td>
        <td>
            <i id="icon_phone" class="fa fa-phone"></i>
        </td>
        </tr>
</table>
<style>
<!--Help here! -->
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was doing .on("click") . Obviously I need more practice, I wouldn't have asked this question at all, its just that I've honestly been trying to figure this out for an entire month.

Comment: @NewPerson: Actually, you can use `on()` as well... I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like you're definitely on the right path, JavaScript is what you're looking for here to get some interactivity on your page.

I'd recommend starting with [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) to get started, and you can check out this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d564w9zf/1/) to see a basic template for a really basic way to get interaction here (changing the contents of a `<div>`.

I'd recommend getting familiar with how jQuery works, and then try changing the css/class of the icon `<i></i>` using jQuery. This should start you on the right path.